# jQuery: animate to zero width if there is some padding inside

Tags: jquery, html, css, input, padding

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcQs4/2/) I created to test the code below. You can click on the red button to expand the input type text to 220px from 0px back and force.

**My question is**: how to make it to be exactly zero when it is zero?
It is not 0px because of paddings that I want to be for some text typed (so there is some space between the left border and the text)

```
<style>
.srchbtn{
 background-color:red;
}
.srchbtn:hover {
 background-color: green;
}
input{
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-right:10px;
}
</style>
<br>
<div style="width: 220px;float: right;position: absolute;right: 10px;">
    <div class="srchbtn" style="width:40px; height:45px;border:1px solid red;float:right;"></div>
    <input type="text" id="box" style="width:0; float:right; height: 41px;" />
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.srchbtn').on('click',function(){
            var box = $('#box');
            var newWidth = box.width()>0 ? 0 : 150;
            box.animate({ width:  newWidth }, 'slow');
        });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the following?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcQs4/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.srchbtn').on('click',function(){
        var box = $('#box');
        var newWidth;

        if(box.width() > 0){
            newWidth = 0;   
            $('input').css('padding-left', '0');
        } else {
            newWidth = 150;
            $('input').css('padding-left', '10px');
        }

        box.animate({ width:  newWidth }, 'slow');
    });
 });
```

**EDIT**

Relying on the comments I came up with this solution:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcQs4/8/)

```
#box {
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    height: 43px;
    width: 0px;

    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}

#box.extended {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/bcQs4/5/ ? (I added the same behaviour to padding-right as well)... I though about this, but you see the padding jumps upon click (please type some text in and test it).

Comment: Thank you, but it is not smooth, it jumps from 10px to 0px.

Comment: Seems like it is possible to fix it this way: create another div, move input in there and make that div position:absolute; right:8px (not 10px). This way the small part is covered. And do not forget to put z-index so you are able to click on the button.

Comment: It's a quite weird effect you want to achieve but why don't just use CSS transition? http://jsfiddle.net/bcQs4/8/

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thank you very much. Please put it as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your fiddle example.

```
[example][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/bcQs4/6/
```

Comment: Thanks, but the padding is not 10px anymore in your example.

Comment: Thanks but once you click to expand, type some text and then click to hide, the padding jumps to zero before it was hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You use this structure:

```
$(".srchbtn").click(function(){
   var width = $("#box").css({width});
   var globalWidth = 0
   if(width > 0 ){
     globalWidth = 0
     $('input').css('padding-left', '0');
   }
   else {
        globalWidth = 150;
        $('input').css('padding-left', '10px');
   }
  $("#box").animate({width:globalWidth},300)
})
```